# Windows server person wanting an easy way to migrate to Linux/Java (LAMP I guess)

Tags: java, linux, lamp, windows-server

open ended question I realize.. and probably well documented somewhere!

I used to write a lot of Java server code way way back - mostly banking etc...

I have been using mostly a windows platform for quite some time.. so I am about to re-embark on the Linux/Java/PHP/MySQL travels...

Just wonder, given the administration for Windows Server, is there anyone out there who has found some good tips.. i.e.

1. Choice of Linux flavours that might be easier to move to from a Win Svr background
2. Any LAMP stack tools that might ease the process of installation/setup..
3. A Java server implementation that is good for beginners to get up to speed.. all I can remember is things like JBOSS etc!

Any thoughts or pointers gratefully received!

Comment: You may find http://serverfault.com useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Ubuntu as the Linux platform.  It is both user and developer friendly.

You might find these directions helpful:  http://www.unixmen.com/linux-tutorials/570-install-lamp-with-1-command-in-ubuntu-910

Comment: As sever environment I would rather choose debian. For development ubuntu does the job as well as debian.

Comment: @zellus, he is a learner.  Might as well start in a nice environment...  Debian _is_ for the experienced.

Comment: Hey thanks guys... yes, took a stab at Ubuntu Server.  Using Rackspace cloud, so got the latest 10.4 version up and running.. now some learning...  I understand why you don't want a GUI on the server.. but right now, I need speed to get going, and so looking at ebox etc to help manage the server/setup the services.. Obviously the old Unix knowledge is coming back.. slowly.. and so I can see why that is the better option all around..

Comment: Ubuntu Server is GUI-less which makes it a bit harder to run graphical programs on.  For now, just use the Desktop and use the knowledge learned to set up a Server instance later.